# Can't install R packages on Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux, r, linux-mint

Running R 3.1.2 on Linux Mint 17, I get a `non-zero exit status` when I try to install popular packages. The full output of an example `install.packages` attempt is as follows:

```
> install.packages("plyr")
Installing package into ‘/home/joe_kendrick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plyr_1.8.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 393233 bytes (384 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 384 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘plyr’ ...
** package ‘plyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
/bin/bash: g++: command not found
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘plyr’
* removing ‘/home/joe_kendrick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/plyr’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpXe52Mz/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("plyr") :
  installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status
```

I get essentially the same message for other packages I attempt to install, eg `ggplot2` and `vegan`, though in many cases it is more verbose as it tries and fails to install dependencies.

This seems like a somewhat common issue, but others seem to have either [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418668/cant-install-package-reshape2-for-r-2-15-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-4) [software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096283/errors-installing-plyr-rcpp) or [insufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994181/install-devtools-package-in-r) [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455887/installing-ggplot2-package-on-ubuntu). I am running the latest stable release of both Mint and R, and I have plenty of RAM and a swap file, so I don't think either of these are causing my issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per the error message

```
 /bin/bash: g++: command not found
```

you need to install a C++ compiler.  I would start with one of these:

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essentials        # key tools
```

or

```
 sudo apt-get install r-base-dev              # many development tools for R
```

or of course

```
 sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp             # to not install from source
```

though the Rcpp you get may be older than the one you need.

There is a list `r-sig-debian` for users of Debian-based systems.

Comment: Thanks a bunch- for potential future readers, `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am running a fairly new installation of Mint 18, and I was missing certain packages. Per the error message in R, I attempted to install "readr", but that wouldn't install because I was missing an underlying package, "libcurl4-openssl-dev". I apt-got that, then readr install without error, and now my packages for RStudio load as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should test which repository here [1](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) works for your Linux Distro. Try add one by one to your '/etc/apt/sources.list' and run:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base 
On Linux Mint 18.3 it worked with:
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
or
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/